# Using owl:oneOf in protege

Tags: owl, protege

I'm working on an ontology and I need to tell protege that one class x can only have the values y and z.

I want something like:

```
Vegetable rdf:type owl:Class;
   owl:oneOf (carrot corn).
```

Must I edit the file directly or is there a way to do it via Protege?

Comment: Think I found it. Using the Object Restriction Creator you can add "only"

Comment: **only** is for Universal Restictions.  The class **[eats only Vegetable]** is the class of individuals x such that for any y where eats(x,y), y  must be a Vegetable.  That is, the class of things that *eats only Vegetables*. What you're looking for, as pointed out [in an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28012832/1281433) is an enumerated class (with one of) and an equivalent class axiom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Class Description you should choose "Equivalent To" option and in Class Expression editor write the comma-separated list of the individuals in curly brackets. In your example:

```
Vegetable equivalentTo {carrot,corn}
```